# How to handle local long-living objects in WSGI env

Tags: python, wsgi, pyramid

*INTRO*

I've recently switched to Python, after about 10 years of PHP development and habits.

Eg. in Symfony2, every request to server (Apache for instance) has to load eg. container class and instantiate it, to construct the "rest" of the objects.

As far as I understand (I hope) Python's WSGI env, an app is created once, and until that app closes, every request just calls methods/functions.

This means that I can have eg. one instance of some class, that can be accessed every time, request is dispatched, without having to instantiate it in every request. Am I right?

*QUESTION*

I want to have one instance of class since the call to `__init__` is very expensive (in both computing and resources lockup). In PHP instantiating this in every request degrades performance, am I right that with Python's WSGI I can instantiate this once, on app startup, and use through requests? If so, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best method I found was mentioned (and I missed it earlier) in Pyramid docs:

From [Pyramid Docs#Startup](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/startup.html#deployment-settings)

> Note that an augmented version of the values passed as `**settings` to the `Configurator` constructor will be available in Pyramid view callable code as `request.registry.settings`. You can create objects you wish to access later from view code, and put them into the dictionary you pass to the configurator as settings. They will then be present in the `request.registry.settings` dictionary at application runtime.

Answer (score 3):

WSGI is merely a standardized interface that makes it possible to build the various components of a web-server architecture so that they can talk to each other.

Pyramid is a framework whose components are glued with each other through WSGI.

Pyramid, like other WSGI frameworks, makes it possible to choose the actual *server* part of the stack, like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/), Apache, or others. That choice is for you to make, and there lies the ultimate answer to your question.

What you need to know is whether your server is multi-threaded or multi-process. In the latter case, it's not enough to check whether a global variable has been instantiated in order to initialize costly resources, because subsequent requests might end up in separate processes, that don't share state.

If your model is multi-threaded, then you might indeed rely on global state, but be aware of the fact that you are introducing a strong dependency in your code. Maybe a singleton pattern coupled with dependency-injection can help to keep your code cleaner and more open to change.

Comment: Upvote, from me as I've learned important stuff from Yours answer, and clean way of achieving my goal is mentioned in my own answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this in `pyramid`, depending on what you want to accomplish in the end. It might be useful to look closely at the [Pyramid/SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.2-branch/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html) as an example of how to handle an expensive initialization (database connection and metadata setup) and then pass that into the request-handling engine.

Note that in the referenced link, the important part for your question is the `__init__.py` file's handling of `initialize_sql` and the subsequent creation of `DBSession`.